# Comment out a part of Vue template element

Tags: syntax, vuejs2, comments

Sometimes it is needed to comment out some element attribute without having to remember it in order to restore it quickly after some tests.

Commenting out whole element is achievable with HTML commenting syntax

```
<div>
    <!-- <h2>Hello</h2> -->
    <span>hi</span>
</div>
```

However this won't work with a single attribute (causes rendering error)

```
<my-comp id="my_comp_1"
         v-model="value"
         <!-- :disabled="!isValid" -->
         @click="handleClick">
</my-comp>
```

The best approach I could see and used before was to make a tag backup by copying whole element and settings `v-if="false"` for it (or comment out whole copied element) and continue to experiment with original one

Comment: I agree that would be useful. What a shame it isn't possible. There are already diffs between template syntax and HTML markup, e.g. case sensitivity and closing tags. Allowing `<!-- -->` (and also the more handy `//` and `/* */`) style comments inside opening tags would be superhandy.

Comment: [Holy war alert disclaimer] Note in JSX, they use {/* */} syntax inside of attributes. So clean and comfortable! <3

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can put an HTML comment inside a component tag, for much the same reason you can't put comments inside an HTML element opening tag. It's not valid markup in either situation. I think the closest you could come would be to place the comment in the quotes:

```
:disabled="// !isValid"
```

Which would have the same effect as:

```
:disabled=""
```

Depending on whether your component can handle that value being missing, that might fit your needs.

Comment: In version 2.6.11, the concept for your solution worked with different syntax. :disabled="false /* !isValid */"

Answer (score 2):

Prefix the attribute value with `data-` or Wrap with `data` attribute.

```html
<my-comp id="my_comp_1"
         v-model="value"
         data-:disabled="!isValid"
         data-_click="handleClick">  # `@` could not be used
</my-comp>
```

or

```html
<my-comp id="my_comp_1"
         v-model="value"
         data='
         :disabled="!isValid"
         @click="handleClick">
         '>
</my-comp>
```

I'll with the attribute set to something like `data-FIXME`.

Comment: personally, the second approach, but using "comment" seems the most natural

Answer (score 1):

I got these solutions to work. I thought of solution 1.

Starting code:

```
<div 
v-for="foo in foos" 
:key="foo.id" 
@click="foo.on = !foo.on /* JavaScript comment. */"
>
  <label>
    {{ foo.name }} {{foo.on}}
  </label>
</div>
```

The Vue directive HTML attribute that needs to be disabled: `@click="foo.on = !foo.on"`

How the final div tag will run:

```
<div 
v-for="foo in foos" 
:key="foo.id" 
>
```

Solutions 1 and 2 keep the disabled attribute inside its tag. I didn't find a good way to make a "raw string". To keep the attribute in the tag, the outer and inner quotes must be different.

sol. 1: I made a new v-bind attribute (`:lang`) to put the disabled attribute in.

```
:lang='en  /* @click="foo.on = !foo.on" */'
```

Sol. 2: Pick a Vue directive. Put the attribute in.

```
v-for="foo in foos /* @click='foo.on = !foo.on' */"
```

Solutions 3 and 4 put the attribute outside the tag.

Sol. 3:

```
<div v-if="false">
  @click="foo.on = !foo.on"
</div>
```

Sol. 4: `<!-- @click="foo.on = !foo.on" -->`

Answer (score 0):

One way to remove/hide component attributes is to create a custom directive for it.

Let's say you create a directive called `v-hide` and put it in your component as:

```
<my-comp  v-model="value" @click="handleClick" v-hide :disable='true'></my-comp>
```

And the output would be:

```
<my-comp  v-model="value" @click="handleClick"></my-comp>
```

Here is a working example:

```js
Vue.component ('my-component', {
  template: `<p> A custom template </p>`
})

Vue.directive('hide', {
  inserted: function (el) {
   console.log('el before hide', el)
    while(el.attributes.length > 0)
    el.removeAttribute(el.attributes[0].name);
    console.log('el after hide', el)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      someValue: 'Hello'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.3/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-component v-model='someValue' v-hide :disable='true'></my-component>
</div>
```