# comment not recognized as such in vuejs

Tags: html, vue.js, intellij-idea, vuejs3, comments

I have an issue with comment not being recognized as such on my vue js. i am trying to test something and to do so i have commented  4 `@click`  that where in radios, but it does creat an error for each of them, the error is as follow.

```
https://google.com/#q=vue%2Fno-parsing-error  Parsing error: unexpected-character-in-attribute-name  
  mypath.vue:52:47
          <!-- @click="afunctionidontwanttocallrightnow=''" -->
```

The error is flagged at the exclamation point in my navigator
as for what the radio look like it is as such

```
<v-radio-group v-model="radiofiltre">
                                              <v-radio
                                              label="somevalue"
                                              value="afunction='somevalue')"
                                              <!-- @click="afunctionidontwantocall=''" -->
                                              ></v-radio>
<v-radio-group>
```

if that does change anything, i am currently running the  front in local with the terminal of intellij IDE

Comment: You can check here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47901814/comment-out-a-part-of-vue-template-element

Comment: the solution offered in said thread is not working in vue3

Answer (score 0):

The tag comment (`<!--  -->`) not going to work within a tag, and AFAIK there is no way to comment an argument.

It might not be the answer you're looking for, but I use a `@` or `_` character as the comment equivalent. The event could be either `@_click`  or `@@click` but not `_@click`. Non-action params could be prepended with `_`, but not `@` since that would make them behave as event listeners.

```html
<v-radio
  label="somevalue"
  _value="afunction='somevalue'"
  @_click="afunctionidontwantocall=''"
  @@click="afunctionidontwantocall=''"
></v-radio>
```

This does no make it as a comment, but rather an attribute that is not used so it *behaves like a comment*.